# Using GStreamer for creating AVI files

Tags: java, video, jframe, media, gstreamer

[image: GStreamer]
So, I was recommended GStreamer to create video files. I was going over their [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/VideoTestTutorial) for creating a video file.
The problems I encountered are:

How do I create an AVI file rather than a YUV something.

What is the source being used there?

I want to give a set of `BufferedImages` or anything else that will show what was going on the screen. I have previously used `JPEGtoMovie` provided bu the Java guys and for that I had to first save all the images to the disk as JPEG, sort them into their correct order from lexicographical order and a whole lot more.
I was planning to avoid that and that is why I was thinking of `Vector<BufferedImage>` or `BlockingArrayQueue<BufferedImage>`

Which all plug-ins do I need from GStreamer to create the `AVI` output?

Sorry I have been asking too many questions today. I have never worked with a media framework before and **I am very dumb**

Answer (score 2):

- The command gst-inspect will list all included elements (components).
- you can produce an avi file from the pipeline: videotestsrc ! encoder ! avimux ! filesink where encoder stands for the encoding element you'd like to use
- an alternative would be to use: videotestsrc ! encodebin ! filesink; here you just build a profile and encodebin will figure our what encoder and what muxer to use to create the format specified in the profile

I did not understood the part around the BufferImages. You can feed images manually to gstreamer (e.g. using [appsrc ! decodebin] instead of [videotestsrc]), but thats a last resort. There are also elements such as multifilesrc that read a sequece of images. Maybe you can give more details what you want to do (where do the source frame come from).

Comment: Basically, I am creating a Screen Recorder. I can use `java.awt.Robot` to capture the screen. It creates a raster of the screen and returns it as a `BufferedImage`. I will be generating 10 images per second. And I want to combine these and output them as a video file. And, obviously, this will be GUI based :)

Comment: and I use Eclipse. I also don't know which all plugins I need. I will need help with that too :)

Comment: I would be glad if you could help be with that :) That is the only last obstacle in creating my screen recorder

Comment: Your task could be easier if you look for a gstreamer source that can capture the screen. On linux we have ximagsrc. Unfortunately I cannot tell you what the windows counterpart is. Basesrc would be the baseclass to use to implement one.

Comment: so, was the issue solved? I also need to create a video stream from BufferedImage, but unfortunatly work arounds with ximagsrc is not a way for me.

Comment: Using a proper image source like ximagesrc is important for performance. Alternatively if you already have images in memory, you can use appsrc to feed them into gstreamer.